# Missing template with a certain locale; rails and cells

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, rails-cells

During Testing my rails app with cucumber I get the following error in the step "And I am on the cases page" only on a MacBook with *english locale*. On Computers with german locale there is no problem. The page renders in the browser without any errors.

```
Missing template cell/rails/display with {:handlers=>[:rhtml, :prawn_xxx, :erb, :rxml, :prawn_dsl, :prawn, :builder, :rjs], :locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf]} in view paths "/Users/jb/swt/features/app/cells", "/Users/jb/swt/features/app/cells/layouts" and possible paths report_table/displaycell/rails/display (ActionView::Template::Error)
      /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cells-3.4.4/lib/cell/rails.rb:140:in `find_family_view_for_state'
      /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cells-3.4.4/lib/cell/rails.rb:154:in `render_view_for'
      /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cells-3.4.4/lib/cell/rails.rb:124:in `render'
      /Users/jb/swt/app/cells/report_table_cell.rb:112:in `display'
```

How can I tell Rails to use only one template for all Languages?

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if there is no view name passed in #render.

1. If you post such questions to our list, you'll surely get support within a few hours: http://groups.google.com/group/cells-and-apotomo
2. Please paste your cell state that is supposed to render.